# Solve the integral $\int \frac{dx}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)^2}$

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{dx}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)^2}$$

I think I need to use replace, but not sure: 
$$x=\frac{u^2-1}{2\cdot u}$$
$$dx=\left(1-\frac{u^2-1}{2u^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, it might be a good idea to first simplify the integrand. We write
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\bigl(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\bigr)^2}&=\frac{\bigl(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\bigr)^2}{\bigl(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\bigr)^2\bigl(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\bigr)^2}\\
&=\bigl(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\bigr)^2\\
&=1+2x^2-2x\sqrt{1+x^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, we have multiplied by the conjugate in the first step, simplified the denominator to 1 in the second step (conjugate rule twice, or squared if you want), and expanded the parenthesis in the last step. Thus,
$$
\int \frac{1}{\bigl(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\bigr)^2}\,dx
=\int 1+2x^2-2x\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx
=x+\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{2}{3}(1+x^2)^{3/2}+C.
$$

Comment: This is a nice answer - short and simple!

Answer (score 5):

If you replace $x$ with $\sinh t$, you are left with:
$$ \int \frac{\cosh t}{e^{2t}}\,dt = C-\frac{1}{6}\left(e^{-3t}+3e^{-t}\right),$$
hence the original integral equals $C-\frac{4+6 x \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)}{6 \left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^3}$.

Comment: um ... OK. but how did you solve the integral?

Comment: @andre1: $\cosh(t)=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$ and it is pretty straightforward to integrate something like $e^{\alpha t}$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is perhaps worth saying that one might guess this substitution because the logarithm of the quantity in parentheses is exactly $\text{arsinh } x$, the inverse hyperbolic sine.

Comment: @Travis: I completely agree with that.

Comment: Edit your formula in a comment, please

Comment: All, no longer need. This I have not worked display. 
You can describe in detail, how did you solve this integral?

Comment: @andre1: we may see that the denominator of the integrand function greatly simplifies if we put $x=\sinh t$, so we just try it, we replace $x$ with $\sinh t$ and get lucky enough to deal with a very simple integral. We recover the wanted primitive by recalling that $$\text{arcsinh}(x)=\log\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right).$$ Clear enough?

Comment: no, I'm sorry. can put this on my example in the answer to write? 
as an algorithm? what did you do?

Comment: @andre1: there is no recipe for integration; integration and differentiation are extremely different under this "algorithmic" point of view. If you want to get skilled, it would be better for you to think a while longer about your assignments, instead of looking for a cooked-up answer or some general algorithm that does not even exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some methods which are strictly less efficient than Jack's (probably optimal) approach, but which are naive in the sense that they only use techniques typically seen in a first course in integral calculus.

The radical expression $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$ in the integrand suggests the trigonometric substitution $$x = \tan \theta, \quad dx = \sec^2 \theta \, d\theta.$$ (In fact, the substitution Jack recommends is just the hyperbolic analogue of this one.) Applying this substitution transforms the integral to
$$\int \frac{\sec^2 \theta \,d\theta}{(\sec \theta + \tan \theta)^2}.$$ One can approach this in several ways:

- Writing the expression out in terms of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ suggests multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 \theta$, simplifying the integral some, to
  $$\int \frac{d \theta}{(1 + \sin \theta)^2}.$$ This can in turn be handled in several ways, including using the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), $\theta = 2 \arctan t,$ which transforms a rational expression in trigonometric functions into a rational expression in $t$. In this case, it's not too hard to manage the resulting rational integrand.
- Alternatively, we might recognize the quantity in parentheses from an uncommon trigonometric identity, $$\sec \theta + \tan \theta = \tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) ,$$
  which is in turn a special case of the [tangent angle sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), $$ \tan(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta}.$$ In this case, the integral becomes $$\int \cot^2 \left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right),$$ which can be handled readily with the Pythagorean identity $$1 + \cot^2 \gamma = \csc^2 \gamma$$ and the fact that $\frac{d}{d \gamma} \cot \gamma = -\csc^2 \gamma$.